# kivy app crashes when using Clock.schedule_interval and sockets

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, clock

When I run the below files the kivy application stops working and crashes without giving an error.

Server.py

```
import socket
import threading

#Constants
IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5455

#Servers
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((IP, port))
print("Connection Established")

#listening
server.listen()
print("Start Listening...")

def on_connection(client_socket):
    client_socket.send(b'Hello Bro what"s up')

while True:
    client_socket , addr = server.accept()

    if client_socket:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=on_connection,args=(client_socket,))
        thread.start()
```

Client.py (Kivy file)

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
import socket

class ClientSide(MDFloatLayout):

    #Constants
    HEADER_LENGTH = 20

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ClientSide, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #Connection Constants
        IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        port = 5455

        #Connectiong to server
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect( (IP , port) )

        print('Running main event')
        self.main_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.join_meeting , 1/10000000000000000000)

    def join_meeting(self,dt):

        try:

            received_info = self.client_socket.recv(self.HEADER_LENGTH)
            print(received_info)

        except:
            pass

class Run(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return ClientSide()

Run().run()
```

I tried running the Clock.schedule_interval inside another clock.schedule_once but it results in the same outcome.

Please help fix this error.

Comment: As a test, try changing the `Clock.schedule_interval()`  to `Clock.schedule_interval(self.join_meeting , 1)` and see if you get the same results.

Comment: No bro it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not crashing, it is just waiting. Your server loops accepting connections and sends some bytes when it gets a connection. But it only ever gets one connection, because your client only makes one connection. Then the server waits for another connection.. The client reads the bytes sent back by the server after it makes the one connection, and then waits for more bytes from the server. At this point everybody it just waiting.

You can fix this by having your client make more connections:

```
class ClientSide(MDFloatLayout):

    #Constants
    HEADER_LENGTH = 20

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ClientSide, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # #Connection Constants
        # IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        # port = 5455
        #
        # #Connectiong to server
        # self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # self.client_socket.connect( (IP , port) )

        print('Running main event')
        self.main_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.join_meeting , 1)

    def join_meeting(self,dt):
        try:
            # Connection Constants
            IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
            port = 5455

            # Connectiong to server
            self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.client_socket.connect((IP, port))

            received_info = self.client_socket.recv(self.HEADER_LENGTH)
            print(received_info)
            self.client_socket.close()

        except:
            pass
```

The above code now makes a new connection on every execution of `join_meetin()`.